# Multiplying a 3x3 matrix to 3nx1 array without using loops

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

In my code, I have to multiply a matrix `A` (dimensions 3x3) to a vector `b1` (dimensions 3x1), resulting in `C`. So `C = A*b1`. Now, I need to repeat this process `n` times keeping `A` fixed and updating `b` to a different (3x1) vector each time. This can be done using loops but I want to avoid it to save computational cost. Instead I want to do it as matrix and vector product. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't know `n` ahead of time, you're probably going to be looping. After finding `C` each time (for a new `b1`), what do you do with the result?

Comment: I know n beforehand. After the product, I add it to another 3nx1 array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build a matrix of `b` vectors, eg for `n` equal to 4:

```
bMat = [b1 b2 b3 b4];
```

Then:

```
C = A * bMat;
```

provides the solution of size 3x4 in this case. If you want the solution in the form of a vector of length 3n by 1, then do:

```
C = C(:);
```

Can we construct `bMat` for arbitrary `n` without a loop? That depends on what the form of all your `b` vectors is. If you let me know in a comment, I can update the answer.

Comment: This works. Thanks! Your C needs to be reshaped though to 3nx1 :). Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @JohnSmith Glad to help. The best thanks is to mark the question answered by clicking the tick mark next to my response. Also, don't use `reshape` to reshape `C`. I just edited my answer to provide a much faster method of reshaping a matrix into a column vector. Cheers.

Comment: I tried to tick but apparently I have to wait 8 minutes before I can do that :D